# Beta Regression Model Selection with CV Lasso in R

Tags: cross-validation, lasso, beta-regression

Is there a package that will do a cross-validatation with regularization for beta regression in R? I'm looking for an equivalent of glmnet for the betareg package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there is a package that does exactly lasso estimation with CV like `glmnet` does. However, for regularized regression with variable selection boosting with stability selection also often works well. This is implemented for beta regression in both `gamboostLSS` and `bamlss`. The latter also contains a lasso regression term `la()`. This is introduced in Groll *at al.* (2018). "Lasso-Type Penalization in the Framework of Generalized Additive Models for Location, Scale and Shape."[RePEc:inn:wpaper:2018-16](https://econpapers.RePEc.org/RePEc:inn:wpaper:2018-16).